# Where do I get SilverlightUIAutomationHelper.dll?

Tags: .net, silverlight, coded-ui-tests

We have a Silverlight solution that worked fine on our old computers. It was set up for coded UI tests, so the projects reference Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.SilverlightUIAutomationHelper.

Then we got new machines, and evidently there's some obscure bit of configuration that we didn't get set up properly on the new machines, because now the reference shows a warning icon, and the Error List window shows the following warning:

> The referenced component 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.SilverlightUIAutomationHelper' could not be found.

I found [this post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vsmantest/thread/1285146f-a254-4c32-9746-64a4da662ba3) that gives the path where this DLL is expected to be found, but that directory doesn't exist. On my 32-bit dev VM, I do have a C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\VSTT\10.0 directory, but it doesn't have a UITestExtensionPackages subdirectory.

What am I missing? How do I install this DLL?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you installed Visual Studio Feature Pack 2?

> Using Microsoft Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Feature Pack 2, you can create coded UI tests or action recordings for Silverlight 4 applications.

It looks like the dll is installed with this.

[Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg413374.aspx)

Comment: I have not. I'll try that and see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Install Visual Studio Feature Pack 2 and Visual Studio Premium.
Then this dll Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.SilverlightUIAutomationHelper you can add in silverlight project by just add reference.

Comment: We already have VS Ultimate installed, and it doesn't include this DLL, so I'm skeptical of your claim that Premium does include it.

Comment: It's in Feature Pack 2, which is an MSDN benefit for VS Premium with MSDN, VS Ultimate with MSDN, and Test Pro with MSDN.

Answer (score 0):

You MUST install Visual Studio 2010 Feature Pack 2 (for which you need an MSDN license). Once you do that, the DLL will be located at:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\VSTT\10.0\UITestExtensionPackages